# Adding indentation when rending variables in template. How?

Tags: elixir

How do I make EEx output multi-line strings, while being indentation aware?

```
template = """
<%= multi_line_text_with_indentation %>
  <%= multi_line_text_with_indentation %>
    <%= multi_line_text_with_indentation %>
"""

text = """
hello
  cruel
    world
"""

template
|> EEx.eval_string([multi_line_text_with_indentation: text])
|> IO.puts()
```

The actual output is:

```
hello
  cruel
    world

  hello
  cruel
    world

    hello
  cruel
    world
```

The desired output is:

```
hello
  cruel
    world
  hello
    cruel
      world
    hello
      cruel
        world
```

There appears to be [`:indentation`](https://hexdocs.pm/eex/1.14.0/EEx.html#module-options) option available to all functions in EEx module (including eval_string function), yet I find myself failing to employ it to add indentation to strings `eval`-ed inside a template.

It looks to me I am missing something very obvious here

Comment: `multi_line_text_with_indentation: String.trim(text)`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin are you sure this helps address my question?  (our of curiosity I've tried `String.trim(text)`, and, perhaps obviously, it had no effect...)

Comment: I am sure it addresses empty lines you want to eliminate. If it was addressing everything, I’d post it as the answer, but I don’t do web at all, so I answered the part I knew.